# Variable with incomplete type objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to have an enum as part of my method signature and I get this hideous error in my .h file:

```
Declaration of 'enum CacheFile' will not be visible outside this function
```

I have this in my h file :

```
 @interface DAO : NSObject

    typedef enum {
        DEFAULT_CACHE_FILE,
        WEB_CACHE_FILE
    } CacheFile;

    -(NSMutableArray *) parseFile :(enum CacheFile) file;



@end
```

My .m file :

```
-(NSMutableArray *) parseFile:(CacheFile) file{
.....
....
}
```

And I get this warning in my m file :

```
Conflicting Parameter types in implementation of 'parseFile:':'enum CacheFile' vs 'CacheFile'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the enum declaration outside of the @interface, update it to proper Objective-C enum idiom (separate typedef) and fix the method declaration:

```
enum {
   DEFAULT_CACHE_FILE,
   WEB_CACHE_FILE
};

typedef unsigned long CacheFile;

@interface DAO : NSObject    
   -(NSMutableArray *) parseFile:(CacheFile) file;
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

Only define it like that in your .h file:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) parseFile :(CacheFile) file;
```

(not with enum again.)