# Why am I getting a type conflict warning on my enum in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, enums

Here is my Constants.h:

```
@import Foundation;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BarcodeType) {
    kNormalBarcode,
    kNoBarcode,
    kGenericBarcode,
    kInvalidBarcode,
    kComicBarcode
};

@interface Constants : NSObject

@end
```

And here is a function that uses it:

.h:

```
@interface Helper : NSObject

- (BarcodeType)barcodeType:(NSString *)barcode;
```

.m:

```
#import "Constants.h"
...

- (BarcodeType)barcodeType:(NSString *)barcode
{
   return kInvalidBarcode;
}
```

Why am I getting this warning on my function, and what do I need to change to fix it?

```
Conflicting return type in implementation of 'getBarcodeType:': 'id' vs 'BarcodeType' (aka 'enum BarcodeType')
```

This code seemed to work fine with older versions of Xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684081/variable-with-incomplete-type-objective-c

Comment: As an aside, your method name shouldn't start with 'get'. There's a specific convention for methods prefixed with 'get' in Objective-C/Cocoa, namely that they return a value by reference in one of their arguments (e.g. [`-[NSArray getObjects:range:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/getObjects:range:)). Instead, you'd typically call the method something like `-barCodeTypeForString:`.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Thanks for the tip, you are correct that I need to change the function name.

Comment: The error is complaining about -getBarcodeType:, but you showed code for -barcodeType:, which is a different method without a "get" in front. The problem is likely in the *get*BarcodeType method.

Answer (score 2):

Check your .h file. My guess is your declaration of the method uses `id`, which conflicts with your definition in the .m file that returns type `BarcodeType`. NSEnum values aren't objects, so `id` isn't valid. You'll want to correct the declaration so the return type matches the implementation.

Comment: I just editing my original question... can you see where the issue is there?

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. This is because I don't have a declaration in my .h file that conflicts with the function from your .m file that you showed us. **Paste the code for the .h file that declares the function**

Comment: I just verified the code you have above compiles just fine - you must have a second declaration of the method somewhere - search the whole project.

Comment: Xcode 5 (that is why you guys aren't getting the warning). `- (BarcodeType)barcodeType:(NSString *)barcode;` which is in `@interface Helper : NSObject`

Comment: Wrong again. It works just fine in Xcode 5 as well as Xcode 4. Paste all your header/source files that use BarcodeType or we'll be unable to help you find the actual cause of the problem. Stop guessing.

Comment: The new code you pasted also works fine. You're doing something wrong somewhere else in code you haven't shown us. Create a full Xcode project example that demonstrates your problem and upload it somewhere. It's getting really frustrating trying to guess which file in your project is doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Just did that and you are correct... a blank project works just fine. I will look through my code and see how else this could be happening and post here.

Comment: OK I feel stupid. I had the `#import "Constants.h"` in my .m file of Helper instead of the .h. For some reason it worked fine that way with Xcode 4 but not 5. I was getting an `expected a type` error in the .h file, which forced it to think it was type `id` in the .m. Thanks for your help.